# Windows 10 not detecting/using headphones correctly

Tags: windows-10, audio, realtek-hd-audio, auto-detect

I've had this strange issue on my laptop whenever I use Windows 10 (When I use Linux I'd have a different issue when I plugged headphones in, they would be correctly detected but there was some minor issue which could be solved by muting or unmuting a sound channel in alsa, or something along those lines, eventually I just created a script that does it automatically to solve it there)

Either way when I plug the headphones in I would get this prompt:[image: Which device did you plug in? With an empty selection in the dropdown menu]

Strangely without any default selection for the device type. (Options are HiFi Headphone, Speaker Out and S/PDIF-Out) It doesn't matter what I select in this menu the result is the same.

Windows just keeps playing sound on speakers, no sound in headphones. However if I restart the computer, then on boot it correctly detects and uses the headphones. If at any point I unplug them, I have to restart the laptop again to actually use them.

Having to restart my computer everytime I plug in my headphones however is not quite acceptable. The laptop model is an MSI GE75 Raider 8SE.

Sound device HWIDs:
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_1220&SUBSYS_14621272&REV_1001
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_1220&SUBSYS_14621272

I've had very few ideas on how to work around this, so far I've unsuccessfully tried:

- Updating the driver (Current version: 6.0.8794.1)
- Going to the sound control panel and disabling and re-enabling the speakers
- Uninstalling the driver

Comment: 1--Has this ever worked correctly (plug in headphone, select it from prompt, headphones work & speakers silent)? 2--Can you find & post the Hardware ID (Device Manager, Sound, right-click Realtek, Properties, Details tab, change drop-down to Hardware Ids)? 3--Post you driver version & date (latest on msi's website is v6.0.8694.1). 4--Uninstall Realtek from Device Manager & reboot or 'scan for HW changes'. 4a--Uninstall Realtek again, but tick box to remove driver SW. Upvote this comment if helpful

Comment: @gregg I am not sure if it ever worked, can't remember, if it did it would have been before I installed the sound driver at all (e.g. when I just installed windows and had whatever it threw at me back then, I kinda need the driver for echo cancellation tho, although it seems like it depends on the weather whether it actually works or not).I'm adding the HWIDs and Driver version to the main question. Will have to try 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you should uninstall it from Device Manager & tick box to 'delete the driver software...' then reboot. Test it after it comes back on, assuming it doesn't work install the [latest driver v6.0.8794.1 from Windows Update Catalog site](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=HDAUDIO%5CFUNC_01%26VEN_10EC%26DEV_1220):
[image]

Comment: I tried this uninstalling and deleting the driver, this did not have an effect. (What actually happened was that after the reboot it was just using an older driver, 6.0.1.8544) I'll try installing the update catalog driver you linked to too but I have a feeling this won't solve things either.

Comment: I cannot find an appropriate version of the 6.0.8794.1 in the link you provided, it's for windows 10 s, or fall creators update. I have the desktop (enterprise/ltsb) windows 10, not the S (mobile)

Comment: If you find my efforts helpful please upvote so I can get credit/reputation. Click the Version column header so it sorts latest on top, LTSB/LSTC/Enterprise still has a version so why don't you update your question with that info (Settings, System, About)

Comment: LTSC is what I meant, sorry, 17763 is the build version, but I thought it kind of stands to reason that I would not be using the mobile version of windows when I am not on a tabletpc or phone...

Comment: I installed this latest version, it had no effect on the issue.